# how to create javascript udf in apache cassandra

Tags: javascript, cassandra, user-defined-functions

I am new to Apache Cassandra and javascript, I need to create javascript udf in Apache Cassandra. I created a simple udf in Cassandra but I am not able to call the function in the query an error pops up

> here are all the details related to my question
>
> my table looks like this

```
 id   | age | course | name    | sex
------+-----+--------+---------+--------
 st05 |  23 | b.tech |  nafees |   male
 st03 |  27 |    mca | lengdon |   male
 st02 |  24 |    mca |  jaanvi | female
 st01 |  22 |    mca |   sahil |   male
 st04 |  23 | b.tech |     jay |   male

CREATE TABLE test.student (
        id text PRIMARY KEY,
        age int,
        course text,
        name text,
        sex text
    )
```

I have also created an index on age column

```
CREATE INDEX age_index ON test.student (age);
```

my function looks like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  demojs (input int) 
   CALLED ON NULL INPUT 
   RETURNS int 
   LANGUAGE javascript AS 'function(input){
    return input;
   }';
```

my query is

```
 select * from student where age=demojs(22);
```

when I try to execute the query I got the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
>   Files\apache-cassandra-3.11.6\bin\cqlsh.py", line 1050, in
>   perform_simple_statement
>       result = future.result()   File "C:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-3.11.6\bin..\lib\cassandra-driver-internal-only-3.11.0-bb96859b.zip\cassandra-driver-3.11.0-bb96859b\cassandra\cluster.py",
>   line 3925, in result
>       raise self._final_exception FunctionFailure: Error from server: code=1400 [User Defined Function failure] message="execution of
>   'test.demojs[int]' failed:
>   com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidTypeException: Invalid
>   value for CQL type int"

can anyone please tell what am I doing wrong here, it will be of great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the body of the function will be like this

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  demojs (input int) 
   CALLED ON NULL INPUT 
   RETURNS int 
   LANGUAGE javascript AS 'input;';
```